# Using `find` for multiple file extensions

Tags: unix, find

I am using the following command for counting the lines of text in JAVA files:

```
find . -name '*.java' | xargs wc -l
```

How can I modify the `find` command parameters to match more than one file extension? For example, I would like use the above operation for CPP, C, and H files.

Comment: This question is actually about the `find` command, since that is where you are searching for matching files.

Comment: Also, use either the `find -print0 | xargs -0` construct or even better and simpler: `find . -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -exec wc -l {} +`. This will avoid any file name issues (blank spaces, new lines and so on) and is (very) good custom.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `-o` option for an OR.  For example, this would list `.cpp`, `.c` and `.h` files:

```
find . -name \*.cpp -o -name \*.c -o -name \*.h
```

Comment: Ah. The `*` no longer needs to be escaped if formatted as code. Totally overlooked that. :)

Comment: Yep, it took three edits by two people but we got it.

Comment: This didn't work for me on OSX (only matched the last -name *.ext) -- I had to use parentheses as suggested by @smokinguns below.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the -o option. For example the statement below finds all png, jpg and gif files in a folder.

```
find . \( -iname \*.png -o -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.gif \)
```

I use the -iname  option so that the match is case insensitive.

Comment: iname isn't available on all versions of find.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ find /path/ -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.c' -or -name '*.h'
```

The “-or” says I’m looking for either/both of two sets.

I recently wrote a quick guide to using find with boolean operators here: http://jamesfishwick.com/2012/linux-find-and-boolean-operators

Answer (score 1):

While all answers are more or less the same, I don't find them readable with multiple name and Boolean operators in-between.

I think this may be more elegant solution:

```
$ find . -type f | grep -E "\.java$|\.cpp$|\.c$"
```

Let's break this up

- `find .` finds all files recursively in current path (change to some other path if you need)
- `-type f`narrows the search only to files (not too much of a speed gain, but still...)
- `| grep -E` I used this to get **grep** recognize ***or*** (`|`) operator in Mac OS X which uses FreeBSD **grep**, GNU **grep** does not need that (check in your `man` file).
- `"\.java$|\.cpp$|\.c$"` regular expression which includes files whose **name ends** with `.java`, `.cpp`, and `.c` (add ones you need)

You can then pipe the resulting list for further processing, e.g.

```
$ find . -type f | grep -E "\.java$|\.cpp$|\.c$" | xargs sed -i '' $'/s/\r$//'
```

This example removes DOS/Windows `CRLF` line ending for OS X/Linux `LF` (this is also OS X `sed` syntax, check for your version specifics).

Comment: I wanted to find all video file types using 25 different extension matching parameters. This was the only approach that worked for me. (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Comment: How well does this perform when you only have a small number of matching files on a large file system with lot of files that don't match the grep pattern?

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

```
find path/to/dir -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2"
```

**Explanation**

1. The first parameter is the directory you want to search.
2. By default `find` does recursion.
3. The `-o` stands for `-or`. So above means search for this wildcard OR this one. If you have only one pattern then no need for `-o`.
4. The quotes around the wildcard pattern are required.